# How can I create a users role in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, user-roles

I want to create a "users" role in Node.js. I have both "moderator" and "admin" accounts but I want to restrict some pages from the moderator. I have to build a middleware but it restricts both the admin from the protected page.

This is my route:

```
function checkRole(role) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    const user = User.findById(req.user._id);
      if (user.roleId === role) {
          next();
      } else {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Payment Page is Restricted');
        res.redirect('back')
      }
  }
}
```

And this is my users model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    gender:{
        type: String
    },
    nickname:{
        type: String
    },
    twitter:{
        type: String
    },
    skype:{
        type: String
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    roleId: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, enum: ['admin', 'moderator'] },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
}, {timestamps: true})

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    var SALT_FACTOR = 12;

    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  });

  userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      cb(null, isMatch);
    });
  };

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I included the `checkRole` function in the page I want to restrict the moderator from, but the admin is being restricted as well. I don't know where this error is coming from.

Comment: Could you post the code where checkRole is being used? I woudl recommend you to debug (or console.log) inside checkRole to verify what you are getting in roleId and role. Regards.

Comment: Actually have gotten it.. Thanks

Comment: Can you separatethe Role table in a separate schema? If yes, How can you default it into a User?